# NSXMLParser not releasing allocations?

Tags: objective-c, swift, memory-leaks

Reading a large XML file (few GB), the Swift program keeps eating memory until my whole system crashes. Not good. After digging around, dropping all useful code, the code below remains. It only defines a `NSXMLParserDelegate` on which one protocol method was implemented. Now when run against a relatively small XML file of 17 MB, the total allocations will amount to 47 MB, and the dirty memory accounts for 77 MB. Now this strikes me as odd, as my code isn't referencing any of the data it is passed.

Is this an error with NSXMLParser, my misunderstanding, or an error with my code?

```
import Foundation

var input = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Process.arguments[1])!
class MyDelegate: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: NSDictionary) {
    }
}

var parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: input)!
var delegate = MyDelegate()
parser.delegate = delegate

parser.parse()
```

[image: Allocations instrument]
[image: VM Tracker instrument]

**Documentation**

> Memory management becomes a heightened concern when you are parsing XML. Processing the XML often requires you to create many objects; you should not allow these objects to accumulate in memory past their span of usefulness. One technique for dealing with these generated objects is for the delegate to create a local autorelease pools at the beginning of each implemented delegation method and release the autorelease pool just before returning. **NSXMLParser manages the memory for each object it creates and sends to the delegate.**
>   [(source)](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/UsingParser.html)

**Update**

When using libxml2's sax parser directly, the memory usage stays steady after a few seconds, with usage around 100 MB. Why is NSXMLParser (mostly just a wrapper) using this much memory?

**Update 2**

NSXMLParser should not be holding on to the data after the delegate has processed them. Most of the structures allocated by NSXMLParser have a ref count of 1 (see screenshot), and thus remain allocated. Manually releasing the memory helps, but that contradicts the memory statement in the documentation and doesn't feel right.

[image: Malloc - ref count 1]

Comment: Does an autoreleasepool help? Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860942/is-it-necessary-to-use-autoreleasepool-in-a-swift-program.

Comment: Where should the autoreleasepool be added? Around the `parser.parse()` call? The delegate doesn't do anything with the objects it receives, so including it there wouldn't pool any object, right? And as the memory issue is inside `parser.parse()`, so cleaning the memory afterwards would have no effect in this case.

Comment: Distinguish between _leaking_ memory and _using_ memory. Your code / Instruments screen shots show _no_ evidence of leaking, so please don't pretend that it does. It _accumulates_ a lot of memory, but if, when your code comes to an end and the NSXMLParser is released, all that memory is released, there is no leak.

Comment: You're correct, leaking is not the correct term. However the high memory usage makes NSXMLParser unusable for large (20 GB) files, as it doesn't reach the end of `parse()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on experimentation, I think that `NSXMLParser` does employ a global `autoreleasepool`. So the `autoreleasepool` only manages the whole parse activity, not individual callbacks to the delegate. So the memory pressure builds up while parsing the file, only being released after the complete file has been parsed.

Pseudo-code:

```
Call function parse
    @autoreleasepool {
        Call delegate function with NSDictionary {
            Bridge NSDictionary to Swift dictionary
            Call my Swift delegate with Swift dictionary {
                // my code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, both the `NSDictionary` and the bridged Swift dictionary stay on the heap until the parse function has finished. To reduce the memory pressure, don't employ a Swift delegate, so there's no Swift dictionary on the heap. Or, stay clear of `NSXMLParser` and implement libxml's sax parser and include more `autoreleasepool`s.