# migrate from objective-c to swift concerning @autoreleasepool block

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to migrate my **objective-c** project to **swift** project. In my objective-c code, I have a function which includes a `@autoreleasepool` block:

```
-(void) doSomething {
   //many things are on going here
   doJobs()

   //@autoreleasepool block here
   @autoreleasepool {
      //access database
      readDB()
      //access backend server
      informServer()
   }
}
```

In swift code, do I need to treat the `@autoreleasepool` block specially? If so, how? If no, can I just do things in the sequential way like below in swift?

```
private func doSomething -> Void {
  //many things are on going here
  doJobs()
  //access database
  readDB()
  //access backend server
  informServer()
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it necessary to use autoreleasepool in a Swift program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860942/is-it-necessary-to-use-autoreleasepool-in-a-swift-program).

Answer (score 0):

You can still use autoreleasepool in **Swift**:

```
autoreleasepool {
   // Put your code here 
}
```

Profile your app to make sure that it actually helps...