# NSData causing leak

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsdata

I have a C `char *cArray` and it's length, and I need to convert it to NSData
I did it with:

```
var data: NSData? = NSData(bytesNoCopy: cArray, length: Int(length))
```

And it's working. The problem is that this is causing some memory leak. I don't know why, but I can see it at the allocation instruments that it's malloc 64 bytes and not freeing it when the function finish or when I set it to null.

This code been called a lot, so I need it to be leaks-free. What can I do to prevent the leak?

Edit: this is the code

```
func on_data_recv_fn(buf: UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>, length: CInt, user_data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> CInt {
    guard buf != nil else {
        NSLog("on_data_recv_fn buf is nil")
        return -1
    }

    //var data: NSData? = NSData(bytesNoCopy: buf, length: Int(length), freeWhenDone: true)
    var data: NSData? = NSData(bytesNoCopy: buf, length: Int(length))
    let succeededWriting = Int(PacketTunnelProvider.sendPackets(data!))
    data = nil
    return CInt(succeededWriting)
}
```

According to memory instruments, there is a leak here.
The sendPackets function does not holding the data so the problem isn't there.

Edit: attached an image from instruments.
[image: instruments image]

Comment: Full method code please.

Comment: What happens if you trigger a memory warning? Is the memory then released?

Comment: The bytesNoCopy initializer does not allocate any data, it just takes the given data and wraps it into a NSData object. So it's strange that you see a malloc at this point. Are you sure about it?

Comment: Where does the buffer come from? You need to ensure that it is deallocated eventually.

Comment: If the data was allocated with malloc then NSData bytesNoCopy will deallocate also on deallocation of the NSData object. So the OP should see here only a free but no malloc. But the OP just sees a malloc and no free. That's strange. I assume: the Instruments output is misinterpreted.

Comment: This is the line I get at the instruments:
[_NSPlaceholderData initWithBytes:length:copy:deallocator:]
and I can see the memory grew up there. 
Ill check again for some bug at other place

Comment: I've added an image of the output from instruments.

Comment: This is an excellent question.  The details of your code seem to obfuscate the real issue.  I also had a memory leak when I tried to mix object files compiled with arc with those that were coded to do their own retain and release calls.  I was also creating NSData objects from a malloc'ed buffer I had gotten from a c code.  And I convinced myself that the NSData itself was leaking something, even if I converted the file to manual memory management and released the NSData myself.  But your solution below did the trick.  Wrap the block in an @autoreleasePool{} block and the leak was gone.

Answer (score 2):

Well, It's seems that if I use autoreleasepool everything is OK for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Memory management of types backed by Objective-C is a vast and interesting topic.  See, for example, here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html

You may also find this question useful:

[Is it necessary to use autoreleasepool in a Swift program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860942/is-it-necessary-to-use-autoreleasepool-in-a-swift-program)

Also, I think there is a danger here if the `buf` passed to `on_data_recv_fn` was dynamically allocated by some C code, which later tries to free it.  Another dangerous possibility: the function is a call-back implemented in Swift and called by C code.  In this case the `buf` might be on the stack.

I haven't played with any of these scenarios, but according to `NSData` documentation, the `bytesNoCopy` initializer makes `NSData` take ownership of the memory and then de-allocate it; it assumes the memory was allocated using `malloc()`, so any memory that was not `malloc'd` should not be used to construct an `NSData` using this initializer.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/initWithBytesNoCopy:length:

There are other `NSData` initializers that make a copy of the buffer and can be safer in those cases.