# NSExpression memory leak?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa, memory-leaks

I want to evaluate dynamically generated mathematical expressions using `NSExpression`. When I run the simple program below, memory consumption quickly sums up to 1 GB and more.

Am I obviously leaking memory or is there anything wrong with the way I am using `NSExpression`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env swift

import Foundation

for _ in 1...100 {

    let expressionString = "((x - y) * ((x * x) - (((x - y) * -1) - y))) + (x * (((x * (y - x)) - x) * -1))"
    let expression = NSExpression(format: expressionString)

    for x in 0 ..< 320 {
        for y in 0 ..< 320 {
            let result = expression.expressionValue(with: ["x" : x, "y": y], context: nil) as! Double
        }
    }
}
```

In the real program, of course, I create a new `expressionString` for every iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Try using an autorelease pool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860942/is-it-necessary-to-use-autoreleasepool-in-a-swift-program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory does not leak, but Foundation methods like
`expressionValue()` can return an "autoreleased" object (and may even
create more autoreleased objects internally).
These are only released when the current autorelease pool ends
(e.g. when execution returns to the main event loop in a Cocoa/Cocoa Touch application).

A command-line application does not have an autorelease pool by
default. You can add one to control the lifetime of autoreleased
objects. For example:

```
for x in 0 ..< 320 {
    autoreleasepool {
        for y in 0 ..< 320 {
            let result = expression.expressionValue(with: ["x" : x, "y": y], context: nil) as! Double
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have to figure out on which loop level to put the pool (to
balance memory consumption vs. execution time).

See also [Is it necessary to use autoreleasepool in a Swift program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860942/is-it-necessary-to-use-autoreleasepool-in-a-swift-program), and 
[Using Autorelease Pool Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-CJBFBEDI) in the "Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide".