# Swift - Calendar Component Extracting Seconds - Memory

Tags: swift, calendar, seconds

I have a requirement where I am reading a list of dates in which I need to extract the seconds from each date to perform some logic.  This is being done on the Watch.  The following example is taking up approximately 50mb of memory which is not acceptable.

```
for count in 1 ... 500000 {
    let currentDate = NSDate()

    let now = Calendar.current.component(.second, from: currentDate as Date)
    print(now)
}
```

Is there a more memory friendly way of extracting the seconds from a Date?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/25860942/1187415

Comment: To be more specific, this is just an example.  I have approximately 500,000 accelerometer records (instances of CMRecordedAccelerometerData).  As the recording is 60hz a second, I have a lot of data to process.

Comment: @MartinR - Your suggestion worked.  Thank you so much!