# "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue " with images

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to fetch images from album and this code fetch all images from specific album, but on scrolling app will close and give error "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue". Please check the code and find the error.(I want to fetch all albums and images like "Lalalab" app without memory warning).

```
 func fatchImagesfromAlbum() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.photoAssets = self.fetchResult as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>

        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)


        self.photoAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: self.assetCollection, options: fetchOptions) as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>

        for i in 0..<self.photoAssets.count{
                let asset = self.photoAssets.object(at: i)
                let imageSize = CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth,
                                       height: asset.pixelHeight)

                let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
                options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
                options.isSynchronous = true

                self.imageManager.requestImage(for: asset as! PHAsset, targetSize: imageSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: options, resultHandler: { (image, info) -> Void in


                    self.images.append(image!)
                    let url:NSURL = info!["PHImageFileURLKey"] as! NSURL
                    let urlString: String = url.path!
                    let theFileName = (urlString as NSString).lastPathComponent
                    print("file name\(info!)")
                    self.imageName.append("\(theFileName)")
                    self.imagePath.append("\(urlString)")

                })

                print(self.imagePath)
                print(self.imageName)
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                        [unowned self] in

                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }


        }
    }
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register(self)

    if fetchResult == nil {
        let allPhotosOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
        fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: allPhotosOptions)
    }


    }
```

Comment: "Please check the code and find the error."  The problem is your approach.  Saveing all UIImage objects in an array is not a good approach at all.

Comment: I also tried to load image with local  path, but it showing "Path does not exist".

Answer (score 1):

Faced such an issue; It has nothing to do with making `weak` or `unowned` references. When objects have been created by either your Objective-C code or using Cocoa classes, what you should do is to deal with [*autoreleasepool*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/2299644-autoreleasepool), try to call your method inside `autoreleasepool`:

```
autoreleasepool {
    fatchImagesfromAlbum()
}
```

<sub>Should it be `fetchImagesfromAlbum` instead of `fatchImagesfromAlbum`?</sub>

Citing from [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html):

> Autorelease pool blocks provide a mechanism whereby you can relinquish
>   ownership of an object, but avoid the possibility of it being
>   deallocated immediately (such as when you return an object from a
>   method). Typically, you don’t need to create your own autorelease pool
>   blocks, but there are some situations in which either you must or it
>   is beneficial to do so.

**However**, it should *not* be required to execute the whole method in the `autoreleasepool`, probably the reason of the memory issue is caused by executing `fetchAssets` or `requestImage` iteratively (inside the `for` loop).

Refers to: [Is it necessary to use autoreleasepool in a Swift program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860942/is-it-necessary-to-use-autoreleasepool-in-a-swift-program)

Comment: When I add all images into Document Directory, in that given code, It will again show that error. How can be resolved that error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a diapatch group then whenever you run loop enter group and leave. After loop has finished iteration you can call diapatch.notify and relaod your UI