# Swapping rootViewController on UIWindow does not deallocate view controller

Tags: ios, uikit

If you swap out a `rootViewController` in `UIWindow`, for example, to present a log in window, if the `rootViewController` has presented (modal) view controllers, those presented view controllers and possibly the old rootViewController **will not** be deallocated.

```
self.window.rootViewController = newViewController
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must *always* do a dismissal of all modals when swapping out the rootViewController, otherwise there will be a retain cycle.

```
if window?.rootViewController.presentedViewController != nil {
    window?.rootViewController.dismiss?(animated: false) {
        window?.rootViewController = newViewController
    }
}
else {
    window?.rootViewController.dismiss?(animated: false)
    window?.rootViewController = newViewController
}
```

If you want to do a nice transition, you could always wrap it in an animation:

```
func transition() {
    if window?.rootViewController.presentedViewController != nil {
        window?.rootViewController.dismiss?(animated: false) {
            window?.rootViewController = newViewController
        }
    }
    else {
        window?.rootViewController.dismiss?(animated: false)
        window?.rootViewController = newViewController
    }
}

UIView.transition(with: window!,
                  duration: 0.3,
                  options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                  animations: transition)
```

Comment: Even better, don’t do that. You shouldn’t change the root view controller.

Comment: This is mostly right. For securely removal, here is one point : `self.myWindow?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
                self.myWindow?.rootViewController = newViewController
            })`

Comment: @matt I see nothing in the documentation stating that changing the root view controller of a window is discouraged, it is a readwrite property. Much safer than dealing with existing view hierarchy in the existing root view controller or using view controller containment in a "base" root view controller.

Comment: @E.Coms Thank you, that is right! I assume completion is called even if there aren't any modals presented. Otherwise you would need a check on `presentedViewController`, I will do some testing later

Comment: I disagree obviously.

Comment: @matt please provide justification so we can update the answer. Otherwise it is just a matter of opinion. Technically this is correct and safe as UIWindow objects support this despite them being somewhat ignored in iOS. You could also swap out windows themselves instead of adding complexity to your root view controller.

Comment: You don't have to do it my way, but as you've discovered there are issues when you mess with the view controller hierarchy from the bottom end like this. I'm saying you would have had those issues if you treated the view controller hierarchy the way it expects to be treated. You are giving a workaround for a self-inflicted wound.

Comment: It isn’t a workaround. It is the proper way to dealloc a view controller manually. Many users swap out the root like this and I thought I would help them do it correctly. You should google “Compassionate Coding” it may be helpful in improving communication style.

Comment: @E.Coms I've tested it and the completion block does not get called if there isn't a presentedViewController, so I've updated my answer to safely work in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

UIKit objects are often released internally using [autorelease](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1571951-autorelease?language=objc). That means that they're not guaranteed to get released right away. You can, however, force things to deallocate by wrapping the function that should release the object with an autoreleasepool.

```
autoreleasepool {
    self.window.rootViewController = newViewController
}
```

For a good explanation of autorelease and autorelease pools, go check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860942/is-it-necessary-to-use-autoreleasepool-in-a-swift-program).