# Xcode: How to find where memory is used (no leaks)?

Tags: swift, xcode, performance, memory

So I have this app that takes 2x9500 lines of data from 2 txt files and parses them into realm.

For that purpose, I loop through those lines like this:

```
func parseToRealm() {

        // each of these files have 9500+ lines of data
        // (basically dictionaries with word definitions)
        let graphicsFileContents = readFile_Graphics()
        let dictFileContents = readFile_Dict()

        // check if counts of two source files match
        if (graphicsFileContents.count == dictFileContents.count && graphicsFileContents.count > 1 && dictFileContents.count > 1) {
            var i = 0
            // make empty array of characters
            var characterArr = [Characters()]

            // loop through two files to get all chars
            for jsonString in graphicsFileContents {
                // parse data from string into json
                let dataFromString = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
                let singleCharJson = try? JSON(data: dataFromString!)


                // parse stuff from file1
                // ... deleted lines for legal reasons


                // DICT information
                let dictDataFromString = dictFileContents[i].data(using: .utf8)
                let singleDictJson = try? JSON(data: dictDataFromString!)

                // parse stuff from that dictionary
                // ... deleted lines for legal reasons

                characterArr.append(Character)

                // Every x characters, write them into DB
                if (i % 150 == 0 || i == graphicsFileContents.count){
                    realmActions.writeCharsToRealm(characterArr: characterArr)
                    print("Writing \(i)-\(i + 150)")
                    // reset array to safe memory
                    characterArr = [Characters()]
                }
                i+=1
            } // end loop file contents
        }else{
            print ("two files have different counts of lines. aborting...")
        }
    }
```

**Explaining the code above:**

- first I put all lines of the txt files into a variable
- then I loop through each line
- I parse each line into an array
- after parsing 150 lines into that array, I send them to realm
- repeat until done

**Problem:**

- I use way to much memory.
- I start at like 40, then I load the files.
- Then it jumps to 80ish
- As soon as the arrays get filled, it constantly grows until 399MB.
- Sidenote: before making steps of 150 items/time, the app would crush
  at 650mb memory on my iphone 6
- It takes at least two minutes.

**The help I need:**

- Most importantly: Where can I see where/on which variables the memory is used?
- Secondary: How to make it faster?

**Screenhot of memory usage:**
[image: 400mb memory usage. what the...]

**Edit:** Showing test results. Seems I have a lot of allocations...
[image: Test results]

Comment: “Where can I see where/on which variables the memory is used?” With Instruments.

Comment: “How to make it faster?” Use Instruments to find the slow part.

Comment: See [Is it necessary to use autoreleasepool in a Swift program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860942/is-it-necessary-to-use-autoreleasepool-in-a-swift-program)

Comment: Edited question to include screenshot of test results... Looks like I got a lot of "total number of repetitions of a particular allocation." from:  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2434/_index.html.

Comment: Now it seems, JSON eats all the memory...