# Parsing Dates takes huge amount of RAM

Tags: swift, memory, memory-leaks

So I have to parse potentially huge log files containing ISO8601 formatted dates.
I use DateFormatter to handle date parsing.
The problem is that memory grows linearly with the number of parsing done.
Here is a simplified version of my code that illustrates the problem :

```
import Foundation

func testMem() {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)

    let dateStr = "2017-10-16 19:01:35.360"
    var after: Int = 0

    for _ in 0..<1_000_000 {
        if let t = formatter.date(from: dateStr) {
            if t > Date.distantPast {
                after += 1
            }
        }
    }
}

testMem()

RunLoop.main.run() //to let the program run
```

Memory usage of this program is around 200Mb.
It looks like Dates are never freed. Profiling this code does not show any leaks.
Because memory grows linearly means I can't really parse large files: the process will eventually get killed because it uses too much RAM.

Conceptually, I don't understand why this program consumes so much memory: only one instance of Date should be alive at any time.

Am I missing something ?

Can I somehow workaround the issue ?

Comment: This should be helpful: [Is it necessary to use autoreleasepool in a Swift program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860942/is-it-necessary-to-use-autoreleasepool-in-a-swift-program).

Comment: Thanks @MartinR ! I'll add an answer based on autoreleasepool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thanks to Martin R's pointer, the solution seems to involve autoreleasepool.
Here is an updated version of the code which fixes the issue :

import Foundation

```
func testMem() {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)

    let dateStr = "2017-10-16 19:01:35.360"
    var after: Int = 0

    for _ in 0..<1_000_000 {
        autoreleasepool {
            if let t = formatter.date(from: dateStr) {
                if t > Date.distantPast {
                    after += 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

testMem()

RunLoop.main.run()
```

Comment: Creating and destroying an autorelease pool is not “free.” You may want to implement  a nested loop, as Rob did here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25880106/1187415.