# swift memory growing indefinitly in URLSession URLSessionDataTask

Tags: swift, urlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I'm running requests in a loop and see that the memory usage is growing unbounded

I think that the `URLSessionDataTask` objects aren't released by the URLSession

My code looks like this

```
let base = "http://myserver.com"

let group = DispatchGroup()

// 10 requests in parallel
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 10)

func request(s: String) {
  var c = URLComponents(string: base)!
  c.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "uid", value: s)]
  let url = c.url!

  var request = URLRequest(url: url)
  let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    semaphore.signal()
    if let data = data {
      let json = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
      print("\(url) \(String(describing: json))")
    }
  }
  semaphore.wait()
  dataTask.resume()
}



// file with million ids
let fileName = "ids.txt"


let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: fileName)
let lines = contents.components(separatedBy: .newlines)

lines.forEach { (s) in
  request(s: s) // make a request for each
}
```

EDIT

Per comments I tried to wrap with `autorelease` but still have memory growth

```
lines.forEach { (s) in
    autoreleasepool {
      request(s: s)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/25860942/1187415.

Comment: doesn't help to wrap it in an autoreleasepool. memory still grows

Comment: Can you show your code with the autorelease pool?

Comment: same but wrapped in the loop 
autoreleasepool {
  lines.forEach { (s) in
    request(s: s)
  }
}

Comment: That's what I assumed :) – The autorelease pool should be *inside* the forEach loop.

Comment: chagned to be lines.forEach { (s) in
    autoreleasepool {
      request(s: s)
    }
  } but still memory is seems to be growing

Comment: You should use a real URL session defined once before your code. Do not clog the shared session.

Comment: I'm just running a simple load test to a service from a throw away tool, I just noticed that the memory keeps growing and that eventually will crash

Comment: Seems that the autorelease pool is working, just need some patience for it to kick in (took a couple of minutes it seems) @MartinR