# Clear memory on cycle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I have an array of images and need to merge these images with different blending options. I found, that during this process memory is not released each step of cycle. Even if there are no references to images which were created. My app crashes during this process because I have many images to merge. Is there any workaround or trick how I can do it without memory increasing?
It is possible to reproduce with the following code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var images =
            [
                UIImage.init(color: UIColor.green, size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1152))!,
                UIImage.init(color: UIColor.green, size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1152))!,
                UIImage.init(color: UIColor.green, size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1152))!,
                UIImage.init(color: UIColor.green, size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1152))!,
                UIImage.init(color: UIColor.green, size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1152))!,
            ]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var result = UIImage.init(color: UIColor.blue, size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1152))!
        for image in images {
            //each step reference to previous result released, but memory is growing
            result = merge(result, image)
            sleep(1)
        }
    }

    public func merge(_ back: UIImage, _ top: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        var size = CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1152)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        let rec = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2048, height: 1152)
        back.draw(in: rec)
        //multiply is just for example, it can be different blending option
        top.draw(in: rec, blendMode: .multiply, alpha: 1)
        var newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    public convenience init?(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, true, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: Orientation.up)
    }
}
```

Array with dummy images and cycle. I added sleep to see it better in `Instruments`  (without sleep it has the same result)
[image: Memory is growing]

As you can see each second memory is increasing.
Any way to keep memory on same level each step?
Many thanks!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25880106/1630618

Comment: yes, it does the job, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap merging into `autoreleasepool` scope:

```
for image in images {
    autoreleasepool {
        result = merge(result, image)
    }
    sleep(1)
}
```

`UIKit` adds objects it produces into the `autoreleasepool` so that they are released at the end of the run loop cycle.