SwiftUI List memory leak in a quite simple scenario
Short problem description:
I'm currently at macos 12.6.1, xcode 14.2, iOS 16.2.
And I wanted to explore how SwiftUI’s List manages cells allocation and deallocation when cells are visible/invisible. For this, I’ve created a simple demo project which has:

Payload – a data model, contains id: Int and image: Image.
PayloadViewModel – manages [Payload], when instantiated just creates 300 values of Payload, where id goes from 1 to 300, and image is just a random noise of colorful pixels with specified size.
ContentView – displays a List of viewModel.payloads in a PayloadRow.

Behavior I expected:
When the app just launched, PayloadViewModel is instantiated and loads ALL images into the array and they are stored in memory, which should be around 52 MB in total. As I scroll the List down, I should not see a significant memory increase, as the application should keep in memory 300 Payload objects in viewModel.payloads, plus duplicate around 5-6 of them to present them in the List, but List uses only those which are VISIBLE.
Behavior I’m getting:
When the app just launched, it’s around 20 MB, then, as we can see in the console, PayloadViewModel starts creating Payload and putting them into [Payloads]. When it’s done, the app is 26.3 MB, not 52 MB as expected (but should be 52 MB, because [Payloads] are already inside a PayloadViewModel ). But when we start scrolling, memory gradually grows. If we scroll to the bottom, the memory usage will be 52 MB, and it seems like non-visible cells are not being deallocated.
Using instruments to figure it out:
I tried to use Allocations instrument for better analysis.
If i launch the app, and wait +- 30 seconds until PayloadViewModel generates all [Payloads] (without scrolling for now), I'm seeing this picture:

By filtering persistent object by the largest size, we can see that VM: CG raster data takes the most size.
If i start scrolling and scroll to the last cell, i can see that now VM: CoreAnimation takes the same size as CG raster data.

My thoughts for now:
I may have an idea of why RAM consumption is low when app just launched(while consumption should be high according to my logic and understanding): maybe it's because images are stored in a compressed format, e.i. jpeg,(whether they are on disk or in RAM), but in order to be displayed - they should be decompressed to their acatual size. But why memory consumption only grows as i scroll - i have no idea.
Any advice is appreciated!
To reproduce, just create a new project, and paste code provided below instead of ContentView:
or just
git clone git@github.com:DmytroKoval8/SwiftUIListExperiment.git
cd SwiftUIListExperiment
git checkout images-for-viewmodel-generated-randomly

or this one, to use images directly from assets, and not randomly generated
git checkout images-for-viewmodel-loaded-from-assets

import SwiftUI
import Combine

class PayloadViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var payloads: [Payload] = []

    init() {
        generatePayloads()
    }

    func generatePayloads() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            for id in 0..<300 {
                let uiImage = self.generateRandomImage(width: 100, height: 100)
                let image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                let payload = Payload(id: id, image: image)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.payloads.append(payload)
                }
                print("Image \(id) generated") 
            }
        }
    }

    func generateRandomImage(width: Int, height: Int) -> UIImage {
        let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        for y in 0..<height {
            for x in 0..<width {
                let color = UIColor(
                    red: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256)) / 255.0,
                    green: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256)) / 255.0,
                    blue: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256)) / 255.0,
                    alpha: 1.0
                )
                context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
                context.fill(CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 1, height: 1))
            }
        }

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}

struct Payload: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let image: Image
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = PayloadViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List(viewModel.payloads) { payload in
            PayloadRow(payload: payload)
                .onAppear {
                    print("Appear: \(payload.id)")
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    print("Disappear: \(payload.id)")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct PayloadRow: View {
    let payload: Payload

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            payload.image
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            Text("Payload \(payload.id)")
        }
    }
}


You probably just need to drain the autorelease pool. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25880106/3141234

@Alexander , sounds logical, but I've just tried to wrap 'for' cycle in it, and it had no effect(

Did you check with instrument what objects or struct are created when running the app ?

@SomeUser You would only wrap the body of the for loop (so the autorelease pool is drained at the end of every iteration), not around the for loop (this would only drain the pool at the end of all loop iterations, but you'd build up a lot of garbage in the meanwhile)

@Alexander yeah, first time I've tried your approach as it seems more logical to me too, but then I've found some article and tried the approach of wrapping around for loop. But both approaches didn't work anyway

Well we can't really help much without more troubleshooting information. You should follow Ptit's advice and inspect this in Instruments.

You could test iOS 18 beta "Fixed: ForEach is now able to reclaim persistent state of unused child views. @State values created by views inside ForEach elements might be destroyed earlier than previously observed. (90667238)"

@Alexander @Ptit Xav Sure, I've updated my post and included some screenshots from instruments. I've also made project available on GitHub, so you can git clone easily to reproduce it. Also I've noticed, that if i load images directly from assets, and will not generate them randomly - the issue will remain same.
If i can provide more info, please let me know

@malhal unfortunately my old mac won't let me update macOS, as well as xCode to get this beta. My current maximum is macos 12.6.1, xcode 14.2, iOS 16.2, and this doesn't seem to be old enough, I've heard that they fixed most of problems with memory leaks in SwiftUI 3 in iOS 16, that's why decided to give it a try

@SomeUser How come the memory track is totally empty?

@Alexander sorry, I don't fully understand what do you mean. You mean two graphs aligned vertically, one of them is Allocations and the one below is VM Tracker ? I just do command+I and then Instruments dialogue pops up, I choose Allocations from there and press the red recording button, and Allocations graph is moving forward, and VM Tracker doesn't

@SomeUser Yeah, I'm confused by the "VM tracker" track being totally empty, but I'm also confused by the "Allocations" graph being empty, then all full, then empty again. I was expecting to see a steady growth, showing memory leaking more and more over time

Compare against https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/30/5/fixing-the-bugs-wasted-allocations

@Alexander i see, seems like it's a visual bug in instruments. I've tried to make graph bigger, and start scrolling right away when app launched, not waiting until images finish generating, and i got this picture https://i.sstatic.net/KPjdu7OG.png

Ah okay, that makes more sense. So it looks like there's growth between ~2s - 35s into the run, then 1:25 to 2:30. Which of the two regions is your loop? What objects do you see allocated during that time range alone?
